# SQLException: Column AD not in specified tables - column AD never specified

Tags: java, sql

I try to create a PreparedStatement:

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT POLBRP, POLTYP, POLNOP, INCPTP, TRMTHP, " +
            "CLTKYP , CANDTP, POLSTP, EXPRYP, OINCPP, CANRNP, PAYMDP,
            KCNFLP, KCRTSP, KACADP, KSCHMP, EXPRYP FROM " 
            + POLHDR + " WHERE POLNOP = " + idNumber + 
            " AND POLBRP = " + branch + " AND POLTYP = " + product + 
            " AND OINCPP <= "+date );
```

And this throws an SQLException: [SQL0206] Column AD not in specified tables.

I have no idea where it's getting column AD from as I never specified it in the select clause (unless I'm being completely blind and stupid)

Can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at your SQL at the point the varaibles have been substituted in to the string.

Comment: Although I might also be blind and stupid, aren't prepared statements supposed to contain either wildcards (`?`) or named parameters (`:param`) ? (in other words: what are the values of the things you build that query string from?)

Comment: you could declare a String variable for the long statement. and system.out.print(sql) to see what sql it generated. with your current code, you could cp and paste that sql in your sql-client to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your variables are strings, e.g. `branch`

```
" AND POLBRP = " + branch + " ...
```

then you forgot to quote the values

```
" AND POLBRP = '" + branch + "' ...
```

but the real solution is using placeholders

```
... AND POLBRP = ? ...
```

which would prevent such problems once and for all, this is what PreparedStatement is designed for

Comment: @Carasel, just make sure that the variables are not holding any maliciously formatted SQL. You have to be absolutely sure that  `idNumber`, `branch`, `product` and `date` variables (as well as any other variables you are using in any other dynamic queries) are not taking their values from user input.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have your answer tabbed to read when this method is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

[Preventing SQL Injection in Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java) shows the proper use of `PreparedStatement`:

> Prepared Statements Variables passed as arguments to prepared
>   statements will automatically be escaped by the JDBC driver.
>
> Example: ps.1

```
String selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE userId = ? ";
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
prepStmt.setString(1, userId);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

From the same source, following in the same section:

> Although Prepared Statements helps in defending against SQL Injection,
>   there are possibilities of SQL Injection attacks through inappropriate
>   usage of Prepared Statements. The example below explains such a
>   scenario where the input variables are passed directly into the
>   Prepared Statement and thereby paving way for **SQL Injection attacks**.
>
> Example: ps.2

```
String strUserName = request.getParameter("Txt_UserName"); 
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userId = '+strUserName+'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your query into this:

```
SELECT
  POLBRP,
  POLTYP,
  POLNOP,
  INCPTP,
  TRMTHP,
  CLTKYP,
  CANDTP,
  POLSTP,
  EXPRYP,
  OINCPP,
  CANRNP,
  PAYMDP,
  KCNFLP,
  KCRTSP,
  KACADP,
  KSCHMP,
  EXPRYP
FROM TableName WHERE POLNOP = ? AND POLBRP = ? AND POLTYP = ? AND OINCPP <= ?";
```

Then use:

```
stmt.setString(1, "ValueOfPOLNOP");
...
```

When your query is being executed `?` will be replaced with the value you passed into [PreparedStatement#setString(int, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my PreparedStatement to work this way now.